# gem install rails -y doesn't work with ruby 2.1.6 in Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi experts about Ruby.

I'm pretty new on this fantastic and funny language, but I immediately meet an error with my command prompt.

I typed, because Win8, gem install rails -y but system said: "gem" is not a batch command or  file and bla bla bla..

Why this?

How can i resolve?

Comment: @Alex Pan It's strange because "Interactive Ruby" works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens if you didn't check the “Add Ruby executables to your PATH” box during the Ruby installation process. In that case your environment won’t know where your Ruby installation is situated. There are two ways you can fix this:

**1. You can try reinstalling Ruby.**

Remember to check the "Add Ruby executables to your PATH" box during the installation process.

**2. You can also try to fix it manually:**

Start menu -> Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings (in the left panel) -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables button

In the User variables section, double click on Path (or select Path and press Edit).

If there is anything else there put a semicolon after it ; and add the path to your Ruby bin folder

Example `C:\Ruby193\bin` or `C:\Ruby200\bin`

Then press OK

**NOTE**: the 3 digits are the version of your Ruby installation. Just go to your C: drive and check the name of the Ruby folder.

Now in the System variables section, press New. For variable name enter RYBUOPT and for variable value rubygems Press OK on the small window and on the other two that remained opened.

Comment: @PHPMan you can verify that everything is working correctly by typing `ruby – v` in your command prompt. It should display a message with your ruby version.

Comment: <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in 'require' cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb <LoadError> from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in '<compiled>'    What does it mean this error?    @Alex Pan

Comment: @PHPMan are you using pik?

Comment: i'm using rubyinstaller   @Alex Pan

Comment: It's strange because "Interactive Ruby" works perfectly.   @Alex Pan